# Is it possible to add a Meteor package only on deploy?

Tags: meteor

I'm wondering if it is possible to add a Meteor package natively (without bash scripts) only when I deploy my application.

I know it is possible to configure the packages to run only when debug is on, but I specifically want to do the inverse, and make the package (AppCache, for instance) to run only when debug is off.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm about to write a bash script to wrap `meteor add package && meteor deploy && meteor remove package`, but it's ugly. A more elegant solution would be ideal.

Comment: Nothing to now. I've given up on some packages because they were slowing down my production, which is terribly sad.